# How can I create an independent Process with ProcessBuilder or set the working directory with exec()

Tags: java, process, runtime, exec, processbuilder

I want to call a Process which is independent from the original Process. So I could use Runtime.`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Xms256M -Xmx256M -jar /home/HauptServer/Games/game1/cloud.jar -p "+port)` but this will not set the working directory. So I used ProcessBuilder an tried this: `ProcessBuilder prb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-Xms256M","-Xmx256M","-jar","cloud.jar","-p",""+port).directory(new File("/home/HauptServer/Games/game1"));` but in this case it is not running independent from my original Process. 
Dou you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)`

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a **separate process**
>   with the specified environment and **working directory.**

Do not use a single line command (`java -jar ...`) . Use the `cmdarray[]` and specify at `dir` the working directory

Example

```
 String cmdArray[] = new String[7];
 cmdArray[0] = "java";
 cmdArray[1] = "-Xms256M";
 cmdArray[2] = "-Xmx256M";
 cmdArray[3] = "-jar";
 cmdArray[4] = "/home/HauptServer/Games/game1/cloud.jar";
 cmdArray[5] = "-p";
 cmdArray[6] = port;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the Process is still a child process of the original and i get this error: java.security.AccessControlException: Illegal Thread Group Access in this line where I started the process:              `Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray, null, new File("/home/HauptServer/Games/game1"));`

Comment: The execution will be dependent of your main process. Some things can not be changed, as the user who launches the process. You have permission to run in the security policy? It allows you to run other processes not java?

Comment: I mean if you're using a standard JVM. If the running process is restricted in some way(eg. Applets), or if you have permissions on the external process to run